# How do I show that $\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \left( \frac{k-1}{n} \prod_{i=1}^{k-2} \left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right) \right)$ equals 1?

Tags: probability-distributions, summation

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \left( \frac{k-1}{n} \prod_{i=1}^{k-2} \left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right) \right)$$

This equals

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} \frac{k-1}{n^{k-1}} \frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k+1)!}$$

but I'm not sure what to do next.

*For k=2, define $ \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{0} \left(1-\frac{i}{n}\right)=1 $.

Comment: J.J.'s answer here gives a probabilistic interpretation (after a slight change of variables) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647533/how-prove-sum-j-knx-j-prod-i-j1n1-x-i-1-1-x-11-x-2-cd/647569#647569

Answer (score 3):

For $1\leq i\leq n$, let $A_i$ be independent events with probability $i/n$. 
Since $P(A_n)=1$, we have $P(A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots \cup A_n)=1$. 
Writing this as a *disjoint* union of $A_1$, $A_1^c A_2$, $A_1^cA_2^c A_3$, 
$\dots$, $\cap_{j<n} A_j^c A_n$ gives
$$1=\sum_{k=1}^n {k\over n}\,\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-{j\over n}\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\def\frc{\displaystyle\frac} a_1:=\frc1n$ and $b_1:=\frc{n-1}n$.

Now divide $b_1$ to $a_2:=b_1\cdot \frc2n$ and $b_2:=b_1\cdot\frc{n-2}n$. 
 
We have $a_1+a_2+b_2=1$.

Continue this way: divide $b_2$ to $a_3:=b_2\cdot\frc3n$ and $b_3:=b_2\cdot\frc{n-3}n$, and so on..

As $b_n=0$, we will have
$$a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n=1\,.$$